# Adding Date to Zip File in Azure DevOps Release Task

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

I have created a Release in the Azure DevOps environment, and added the Archive File task to my stage. I want the name of the zip file to include the date the file was created on, but there doesn't seem to be syntax that allows me to do it. Does anyone know of a way to include the date in the file name?

[image]

Comment: Try this - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=classic%2Cbatch#set-variables-by-using-expressions

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks you could not use that directly in `Archive file to create` of the task, the workaround is to configure the `Release name format` with `$(Date: yyyyMMdd)` in the release pipeline -> `Options` like below.

[image]

Then in the task, reference it with [`$(Release.ReleaseName)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/release/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=batch#default-variables---release), e.g. `xxxxxx/test-$(Release.ReleaseName).zip`.

[image]

Run the task, it works on my side.

[image]

Comment: That's exactly what I needed. Thank you for you help!